# How to convert Ascii to Unicode in java?

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I have a string is half-size font and i want to convert it to full size. I was tried to use this code

```
final String x = "01589846";
    String b = "";
    System.out.print("01589846");
    int y = 0;
    final char[] list = x.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        y = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list[i]));
        final char unicode = (char) (y + 65296);
        b += unicode;

    }
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

it actually working but it only working with number.
Anyone have another way for this ? please help me !!!!!

Comment: What exactly is "half-size font" and "full size"?

Comment: FYI, the `char` type in Java is obsolete. Instead, use Unicode code point integer numbers.

Comment: He might be talking about half-width forms: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)

Comment: Those single tick marks around your code snippet do not belong there. Instead, either indent all lines by four spaces, or wrap block in a pair of triple back-ticks. Also, your last curly brace appears to be unbalanced.

Comment: @BasilBourque - on obsolete char: true enough, I suppose, but the evidence suggests that the OP is only interested in codepoints < 0x80.  In any case, are there codepoints outside the BMP that have "fullwidth" counterparts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
final String x = "012345 abcdef ABCDEF";
System.out.println(x);
        
String b = "";
final char[] list = x.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if(Character.isDigit(list[i])) {
        b += (char)(list[i] - 48 + 0xFF10);
    } else if(Character.isUpperCase(list[i])) {
        b += (char)(list[i] - 65 + 0xFF21);
    } else if(Character.isLowerCase(list[i])) {
        b += (char)(list[i] - 97 + 0xFF41);
    } else if(Character.isWhitespace(list[i])) {
        b += list[i];
    } else {
        b += (char)(list[i] - 33 + 0xFF01);
    }
}
System.out.println(b);
```

Output:

```
012345 abcdef ABCDEF
０１２３４５ ａｂｃｄｅｆ ＡＢＣＤＥＦ
```

Comment: FWIW, I'd code `'0'` rather than `48`, etc.  I think it makes the logic just a little clearer.

Comment: Also, this code erroneously converts [digits outside the range 0-9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)), alphabetics outside A-Z or a-z.  That might be ok for the OP's use-case -- my answer has similar unchecked assumptions -- but I think it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Java Strings **are** Unicode. They don't need converting.  Java does not natively use ASCII.

You apparently wish to map one set of Unicode characters to another. The appropriate tool for that would be a Map, but you'll have to populate the Map with your desired conversion taken from the [Unicode code charts](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UFF00.pdf).

There may be some algorithmic way to do this for particular subranges; you seem to have discovered a way that works for (western) digits.  Note that the fullwidth digits occupy codepoints 0xFF10 to 0xFF19, so the conversion formula is `digit - '0' + 0xff10`.  0xFF10 is 65296 decimal, but the hex is clearer, since it's what is used in published code charts.

Actually, it looks to me that the same thing works for all characters in the range SPACE to '~', presumably by design.  Thus

```
for (int i=0; i<list.length; i++)
   list[i] += 0xff00 - ' ';
```

Here, I simply assume without checking that `list` will only contain characters in the range of SPACE to '~', i.e., the Unicode range that corresponds to graphic (printable) ASCII characters.  Dealing with other characters, for example Katakana, is more involved.